# how to evaluate the integral with Gaussian function when the upper limit is not infinity and the 'kernel' is not unity but x?

Tags: integration, gaussian

Can anyone please help me with this integral? There are tricks you can pull off to do the integral when the upper limit is infinity, but it gets difficult when the upper limit is a per-specified number. Here f(x)=x or constant. Basically, I want to compute the expected value of f(x) using a normal (non-standard) distribution. I would like to be able to express the result in terms of C (upper limit), the mean and the standard deviation of the normal distribution. Thank you!

$$
\int_{ - \infty }^c {f(x){1 \over {\sqrt {2\pi } \sigma }}
e^{ - {1 \over 2}\left( {{{x - \mu } \over \sigma }} \right)^{\,2} } dx} 
$$

Comment: I took the liberty to directly insert the formula, is it ok with you ?

Comment: Yes. I was being stupid.  When f(x)=x and the power of exponential is just x^2, it's a straightforward elementary integral. Now the power of exponential has other constant terms. Using some changes of variables, you can transform the integral here to (a*x+b) times a standard normal distribution which will inevitably involve the use of some error function erf(). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is very a simple question. I may have been just stupid. It only gets tricky when f(x) is a constant where you would need to use erf function. It is trivia when f(x) = x...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).